# Need help identifying this chip / package

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, qfn

I got this faulty chip out of a Corsair AIO water cooling unit.

I can't identify this chip or its package. Pictures of the chip are below.

The size is rather small, 1mm x 1.2mm. The markings on top state 'AV BG,' which gave me no results in my research.

I suspect it could be a QFN-8 or some form of WSON-6.
It would mean a lot to me if someone has some hints. Anything helps so I may find this chip and repair the AIO...

[image: Front View]

[image: Back/Pad View]

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question to include the markings in the title so that you're not relying on someone who knows the answer to have to open the question to find out what it's about. Include "QFN-8" in there as well.

Comment: Not a qfm, looks like CSP to me

Answer (score 1):

It's a Renesas device in a `STQFN-8` package, likely a [SLG46108](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/slg46108-datasheet) PLD. (Devices in this package seem to be orginally made by Silego which was acquired by Dialog which was acquired by Renesas. )

[image]

(Source: [renesas.com](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/slg46108-datasheet))

The markings used on these devices don't seem to contain a code that can be used to easily identify the product or at least this information isn't made public:

[image]

I found the following devices in this package, but there might be more:

- [SLG46108](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/slg46108-datasheet) (PLD)
- [SLG7RN46452](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/slg7rn46452-datasheet) (Reset IC)

The SLG7RN46452 is probably just a pre-configured SLG46108. The datasheet states that Renesas lets you order these chip pre-configured with a custom configuration and product code. The `BG` marking might be specific for this configuration by Corsair.